# Java Toolkit not displaying image

Tags: java, image, frame

I am doing a tank game but the tank's paint method doesn't display my image. Here is the paint method of the Tank class.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("E:/test/tank.jpg");
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 300, null);
}
```

And here is the code for my frame's constructor(I just used the constructor instead of in the main method.

```
class MyFrame extends Frame{
    MyFrame(String s){
        super(s);
        setBounds(0,0,400,400);
        Tank t = new Tank();
        add(t);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

the problem is that the picture doesn't display but the path is correct.
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I changed the image to another jpg and it worked. But the original one didn't.

Comment: Instead of `public void paint(Graphics g)`, try `@Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

Comment: It saids: The method paintComponent(Graphics) of type Tank must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: @the programmer this information is not enough.provide more information .what is your tank class is it a jcomponent ? are you getting any errors?

Comment: Don't read the image in the painting method.

Comment: @Fast Snail the tank class is component, I am using awt not swing

Comment: @camickr I putted it in the class as one of the properties, didn't work.

Comment: Also use `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 300, this);` and don't keep loading the images within the paint methods, it's not particularly efficent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. First, sorry for answering my own question. I found out that the image was broken and didn't work. I used another image and it worked. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for all you responses. I figured it out. Thanks!